# Calculate this integral returns undefined

Tags: numerical-integration

```
Limit[     (Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[3 t + 2] + 3] , {t, 0, x}]^2)   / 
  Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[6 t - 2] + 5] , {t, 0, x}] , x -> Infinity]
```

This can be solved but mathematica cant give a result. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* infinity limit

`Assumptions -> x > 0` helps Mathematica to find these integrals

```
Limit[(Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[3 t + 2] + 3], {t, 0, x}, 
     Assumptions -> x > 0]^2)/
  Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[6 t - 2] + 5], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 0], 
 x -> ∞]
(* (4 E^3)/3 *)
```

Validation

```
Plot[{(NIntegrate[Sqrt[Exp[3 t + 2] + 3], {t, 0, x}]^2)/
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[Exp[6 t - 2] + 5], {t, 0, x}], (4 E^3)/3}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry limit is to infinity

Comment: I should read about assumptions

Comment: This packages the needed assumption part fairly compactly. `Assuming[x > 1000, Limit[Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[3 t + 2] + 3], {t, 0, x}]^2/ Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[6 t - 2] + 5], {t, 0, x}], x -> Infinity]]`

Answer (score 2):

Integration in *Mathematica* treat every symbol as it can be any number (`Real`, `Integer`, `Complex`). Type of number defiantly change the results in some cases (as this one) and does not effect results in other cases.

In your case, the Integration depends on the value of `x` (combination of `Imaginary` and `Real` pares of `x` in case `x` is `Complex`)
If you want to get specific value for the integration without `Conditions` you either specify the rang of values of `x` that satisfy the result (using `Assumptions` or `Assuming`) or disable the `ConditionalExpression` using `GenerateConditions -> False`. as follows:

```
Limit[
  (Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[3 t + 2] + 3], {t, 0, x}, GenerateConditions -> False])^2/
  Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[6 t - 2] + 5], {t, 0, x}, GenerateConditions -> False],
  x ->∞]
```

> ```
> (4 E^3)/3
> ```

Comment: The answer is updated. Thanks Öskå :):).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of conditionals in there, that you need to carefully look at. Why not do this step by step so you see the issue?

```
Clear[x, t]
int1 = Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[3 t + 2] + 3], {t, 0, x}]
int2 = Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[6 t - 2] + 5], {t, 0, x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By passing them for now, we get

```
 expr = (First@int1)^2/(First@int2)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Limit[expr, x -> 0]
 (*0*)
```

Comment: the first conditional fails for all real x `(e^3x<=0)`.. makes me wonder why @algohli's answer works...